# Android NDK + Two Shared Libraries + RTTI + Dynamic cast = Impossible

Tags: android, android-ndk, rtti

I've been at this for 4 hours so far on a Sunday.  I'm about to give up.
I've tried literally every post I've found on the internet and this simply will..not..work!

Any instance of `dynamic_cast` with references or pointers either returns null or flat-out crashes my program.  This is absolutely 100% critical to my entire application architecture, and I may just have to go to 200 MB static libs if I can't get this going.

I'm building with `-frtti` (there's no -fno-rtti), and linking with `-Wl,-export-dynamic` (also tried `rdynamic`) on all my libraries.

I've also manually overrode Java's `loadLibrary()` by using my own `dlopen(fn, RTLD_NOW | RTLD_GLOBAL)` to open each lib (I've tried every possible combination of flags.

Is this simply not possible?  Leave it to android to take something that has worked well for me for an entire decade on other platforms and turn it into a huuuuge problem that cannot be solved.

Comment: May share your logs and the code in question?

Comment: I appreciate you responding.  I may actually have it.  Stumbled onto some advice about linking against libstdc++_shared instead of the oddly default "static" version.  Will update back here soon.

Comment: Much to my complete shock, yet another piece of freaking advice from android's official NDK docs don't fix this problem.  Linking against c++_shared does absolutely nothing to fix the problem.  My codebase is extremely complex, over 100 thousand lines.  The snippet that is crashing is here

```      auto ee = dynamic_pointer_cast<EntityModelEditable>(ent);
      HitTestResult bbHit = { nullptr, float3::zero, float3::zero, 0 };

      lock_guard<mutex> locker(ee->getEditDataLock());
```

ee is guaranteed to be the right kind of type and this works on all other builds

Comment: I give up, this is going to be a static lib build.  I can't take another second of dealing with this should-be-inexistent problem.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/master/docs/user/common_problems.md#rtti_exceptions-not-working-across-library-boundaries. The C++ ABI makes it tricky to get RTTI right when dynamically loading libraries. Each of your types must have a key function (a virtual, non-inline, non-destructor method) for RTTI to work across shared library boundaries.